# From a security perspective is ok to write out the error from a ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security, error-handling

My ajax calls typically go something like this:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Controller/GoDoWhatever',
                    contentType: 'application/json;',
                    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                    success: function (data) {
                        // all good
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
```

What I'd like to know is when we do hit an error what is ok or not ok to do with error? Once code goes live the console.log only serves a purpose to a developer really imo. However, can potentially personal data brought back from the error say if I've wrote the controller in an insecure way. If there is a chance the error can give a nefarious user an edge then what should I be doing, not console.log at all or completely remove the error functionality? Hope I've explained this correctly, thanks in advance :)

Comment: The user can access anything that's sent to the browser using DevTools. There's no security implications from logging it explicitly, except that they can see it more easily.

Comment: The error will appear in the network and the response object anyway. It's up to the backend to not return sensitive data in the error responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can access it through devtools anyway. Doesn't matter if you console.log it or not.

Make sure the server sends safe error messages, then anything you do with it will be safe.

Public APIs obviously should have safe messages, and you should handle errors (and send a safe error back to the client) for all API routes in your own server.

Comment: can the error be retrieved from devtools if I remove the "error:..." aspect?

Comment: @MartinCooke Yes. Anything and everything your client-side code has access to, your users can access via the devtools. Even if you don't say it#s an error

Comment: ah ok, so I may well leave it in, its far more important (by the sounds) the controller is not returning data I wouldn't want returned, ie an error message with PI data in, many thanks for your response :)

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm glad you understand